# Autosave in Gnote

Tags: gnote

Ubuntu 22.04, Gnote 42.0

After upgrading to the new Ubuntu from 20.04 Gnote doesn't save notes automatically

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Preferences --> Restore Session is not exactly the same, but it's close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By default, Gnote keeps notes created by the user at `~/.local/share/gnote/` and their permissions are Owner: Me Read and write, Group: your-username Read-only, and Others Read-only. Backup your Gnote notes and save them in a safe place.
2. Remove and purge Gnote and then reinstall it.

   ```
   sudo apt purge gnote
   sudo apt install gnote
   ```
3. If this doesn't work try deleting all your Gnote notes except for the backups, and check if Gnote can save notes automatically if it is started empty without any old notes in its Notebook(s). You can import your old notes later from the backed up notes.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was in permissions to the ~/.local/share/gnote/ folder